# How to get the partial factor representation of $\frac{1}{x^2+4x+1}$?

Tags: factoring, partial-fractions

I've been trying to factor this, but I don't see it.

What is the partial fractions representation of $$\frac{1}{x^2+4x+1}$$?

Comment: any own effort???

Comment: @tired Why ask a question if it was clear to me?

Comment: i guess u tried something for ur own before asking for help here?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Let $\alpha, \beta$ be the roots of $x^2+4x+1$. Then $$\frac{1}{x^2+4x+1} = \frac{1}{(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)} = \frac{1/(\beta-\alpha)}{x-\beta}+\frac{1/(\alpha-\beta)}{x-\alpha}$$

Comment: How's the last inequality seen?

Comment: Just put $\frac{1}{(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)}$ into partial fractions in whatever way you usually put things into partial fractions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does, but not over the rationals.  You can use the quadratic formula or complete the square to say $x^2+4x+1=x^2+4x+4-3=(x+2+\sqrt 3)(x+2-\sqrt 3)$ and the denominators of the partial fractions are those two factors.

Comment: "denominator for both partial fractions" you meant? Not that the part. fractions are $\frac{1}{(x+2+\sqrt{3})} + \frac{1}{(x+2-\sqrt{3})}$, but rather $\frac{1}{(x+2+\sqrt{3})(x+2-\sqrt{3})}+\frac{1}{(x+2+\sqrt{3})(x+2-\sqrt{3})}$

Comment: No, your fraction is already $\frac{1}{(x+2+\sqrt{3})(x+2-\sqrt{3})}$.  We are expanding it to $\frac{a}{(x+2+\sqrt{3})} + \frac{b}{(x+2-\sqrt{3})}$ but I did not find $a,b$